# How to do a Loop in Android?

Tags: android, loops, asynchronous

So, I'm doing an app and I'm having problems. What I want is when some one click at an Image Button this Image Button will be moving randomly at the screen until you close de app. So, I have to use AsyncTask because there is a View to me modified, but I don't know how to do an infinite loop at the AsyncTask class. I know that I have to use the onPostExecute to change the View position, but what about the loop? The app it's a joke that I want to make with my friend.

This is the main acitivity:

```
package br.hue.brfernandobr;

import java.util.Random;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class BrFernandoBr extends Activity 
{

    public ImageButton imageButtonBrFernando;
    RelativeLayout layout;

    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_br_fernando_br);

        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById( R.id.layout );

        setVolumeControlStream( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC );

        player = MediaPlayer.create( this, R.raw.brbrhuehue );

        imageButtonBrFernando = (ImageButton) findViewById( R.id.imageViewBrFernando );
        addListenerImageButtonBrFernando();

    }

    private class GameTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute( Void result )
        {

            moveImage();
            changeImageColors();
            playSong();

        }

    }

    private void addListenerImageButtonBrFernando() 
    {

        imageButtonBrFernando.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {

                new GameTask().execute();

            }

        });

    }

    private void moveImage()
    {

        Random random = new Random();

        int x = random.nextInt( layout.getWidth() - imageButtonBrFernando.getWidth() / 2 );
        int y = random.nextInt( layout.getHeight() - imageButtonBrFernando.getHeight() / 2 );

        imageButtonBrFernando.setX( x );
        imageButtonBrFernando.setY( y );

    }

    private void changeImageColors()
    {

        Random random = new Random();

        int numColor = random.nextInt( 5 );

        switch ( numColor ) {
        case 0:
            imageButtonBrFernando.getBackground().setColorFilter( Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
            layout.setBackgroundColor( Color.RED );
            break;
        case 1:
            imageButtonBrFernando.getBackground().setColorFilter( Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
            layout.setBackgroundColor( Color.BLUE );
            break;
        case 2:
            imageButtonBrFernando.getBackground().setColorFilter( Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
            layout.setBackgroundColor( Color.GREEN );
            break;
        case 3:
            imageButtonBrFernando.getBackground().setColorFilter( Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
            layout.setBackgroundColor( Color.YELLOW );
            break;
        case 4:
            imageButtonBrFernando.getBackground().setColorFilter( Color.MAGENTA, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
            layout.setBackgroundColor( Color.MAGENTA );
            break;
        }

    }

    private void playSong()
    {

        if( !player.isPlaying() )
        {

            player.start();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @ArtooDetoo
After the first click the Image Button needs to stay moving randomly  without stop, so I need a loop, and I can't do a loop at the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do properly, you don't need an ASync task, simply change position in the onClick handler of your image button. This way it's event driven.

If you want the button to continue moving after the first click, simply use a timer with a short-ish timeout to move the button
you can use runOnUiThread as follows:

first, here's your onClick listener to get the process started

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 500,500);
    }
```

then your timer task

```
    private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask{

    @Override
    public void run() {        
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {              
        @Override
        public void run() {
                // move your button here
            }
        });
    }       
}
```

Comment: After the first click the Image Button needs to stay move randomly  without stop, so I need a loop, and I can't do a loop at the main thread.

Comment: I tried that, but I can't touch a View from that Thread, that is why I think I need to use a Async Task, I need to comunite with the main thread, to move the Image Button. I think that this is not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this.

```
public void doStuff(){
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // you're in the main thread here
                }
            });
        }
    }, 500, 500);

}

Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was tu use a Timer.

```
T = new Timer();
        T.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {         
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {

                            playSong();
                            moveImage();
                            changeImageColors();

                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 1000, 1000);
```

I had to use a RunUiThread method so I could change the views.